# What would be the reason for kaaba being 666 nautical miles from al aqsa masjid?

Tags: kaabah

Salaam everyone, i would like to know your views on the matter.
Kaaba is 666 nautical Miles from masjid al aqsa. (767 miles) , what would be the reason if any ? i am referring to the christian belief of the number 666 being a negative one, why then would Allah (SWT) place both sites at this range?

Comment: i would also like to highlight that al aqsa masjid is also the same area as Solomons (A.S) temple that the jews and christians(?) hold holy

Comment: I suppose the real question is, why would Allah be measuring distance across a desert in nautical miles a thousand plus years before the unit of measurement was even invented?

Comment: i get what your saying, but doesn’t the fact still stand that the nautical mile was invented with the precision it has been with, and measures this distance regardless?

Comment: According to the distance measure tool on google maps, the distance between the two is 1,237.98 km or 668.46 nautical miles.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidences sometimes happen.

If it's a coincidence doesn't mean it was purposefully chosen by Allah.

The number 666 is just like any other number.